# How to update JavaScript variable using PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript file named a `pricing.js` which contains this content in it:

```
var price_arr = new Array('&#36; 16.95','&#36; 30.95','&#36; 49.95','&#36; 70.95','&#36; 99.95','&#36; 109.95','&#36; 139.95','&#36; 155.95','&#36; 199.95','&#36; 460.95');
```

But I want to to update this part of JavaScript file using PHP so please help me in this how can I update this part of the content from JavaScript file using PHP?

```
 '&#36; 16.95','&#36; 30.95','&#36; 49.95','&#36; 70.95','&#36; 99.95','&#36; 109.95','&#36; 139.95','&#36; 155.95','&#36; 199.95','&#36; 460.95'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please understand that Javascript is Client Side code and PHP is server side code.

There can be 2 possible ways or scenarios which you want to achieve:

1. If you want to manipulate the JS file before sending it to client, you can rename the Javascript file to have .php extension and write php code to provide a variable. For Ex:

   ```
   <?php   
   // write php code to create a string of values using a for loop  

   $price_array_string = "'&#36; 16.95','&#36; 30.95','&#36; 49.95',
        '&#36; 70.95','&#36; 99.95','&#36; 109.95','&#36; 139.95','&#36; 155.95','&#36; 199.95','&#36; 460.95'";


   // Javscript Code var price_arr = new Array(`<?`php echo $price_array_string ?>);
   ```
2. The other alternative is that you get the value of price array by making an Ajax Request to a PHP web service.

Answer (score 0):

Simply give the pricing.js file a .php extension. You can then include PHP in the javascript file the way you would for any other page. Just be sure your HTML code specifies that it's still "text/javascript" when you load it. You'll probably want to set the content-type in the PHP file as well, like so: `header("Content-type: text/javascript");`

Answer (score 0):

Using your PHP script you can put a value in an HTML5 data attribute of an element on your page and then read it from your JavaScript, e.g. `<body data-array="'&#36; 16.95','&#36; 30.95'">` can be generated with PHP, and then read with JS: `var are = new Array($('body').attr('data-array').split(','))`. Here jQuery is used in order to read the attribute value, but you can also do it with pure JavaScript.